# Time data does not match format '%yyyy-%mm-%dd

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have the column "date of registration" in the below format.

```
array(['01JAN2018:00:00:00.000000000', '01JAN2019:00:00:00.000000000',
   '01JAN2020:00:00:00.000000000', ...,
   '09FEB2018:00:00:00.000000000', '09FEB2019:00:00:00.000000000',
   '09FEB2020:00:00:00.000000000'], dtype=object)
```

I am trying to convert this to the below format.

```
array(['1993-04-29', '1993-04-15', ..., '2019-08-29', '2019-08-30',
   '2019-08-31'], dtype=object)
```

I tried this conversion using to_datetime function but I get the error "ValueError: time data '01JAN2018:00:00:00.000000000' does not match format '%yyyy-%mm-%dd' (match)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'`:

```
pd.to_datetime(['01JAN2018:00:00:00.000000000', '01JAN2019:00:00:00.000000000',
   '01JAN2020:00:00:00.000000000', 
   '09FEB2018:00:00:00.000000000', '09FEB2019:00:00:00.000000000',
   '09FEB2020:00:00:00.000000000'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Out:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2018-02-09',
               '2019-02-09', '2020-02-09'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

More information [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Chains that with `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` if you want sting output.

Comment: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f'). Once the assignment is made, the output format changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `pd.to_datetime` function especifying the format.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array(['01JAN2018:00:00:00.000000000', '01JAN2019:00:00:00.000000000',
   '01JAN2020:00:00:00.000000000',
   '09FEB2018:00:00:00.000000000', '09FEB2019:00:00:00.000000000',
   '09FEB2020:00:00:00.000000000'])

b = pd.to_datetime(a, format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f")
np.array(b)


Out[]:
array(['2018-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2018-02-09T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2019-02-09T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-02-09T00:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```